# Azure web application can not find Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-service-runtime

The application was recently upgraded from Azure SDK 1.7 to 2.0 along with a bunch of other changes.

It spent a month in testing (hosted on Azure as it is on Live) and was all fine. We then released it Live where it was running for a few weeks with no problems, now out of the blue (no changes were made) I am getting this error when the web role is attempting to do stuff.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I can not find a reference to 1.7 anywhere in the project (they all use 2.0, I have even opened each project file in txtpad and double checked the references.), I have tried to add a binding redirect but still get the same error. What really stumps me is how it worked for so long and then started doing this? The testing team are positive that it was working when it went through testing and released. Any hints on what else I could try to resolve the issue greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I remoted in and found this in the event log, The application '/' belonging to site '19369254' has an invalid AppPoolId '14f1780d-4dcb-48b5-88eb-8e59eda5aff8' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored. May have something to do with it?

Comment: If you do have Visual Studio Ultimate, I highly suggest using Intellitrace to track down the issue. Even if you are not directly referencing Service Runtime 1.7, there might be some other library you use that has explicit reference to SR 1.7. I've this happening quite a few times. Say Azure Diagnostics old version, or WindowsAzure.Configuration old version, etc. You might even (I don't know) reference a third party Azure extensions which are referencing the old Service Runtime. Such as additional plugins from the Azure Plugin Library.

Comment: May it be that the assembly is referenced from web.config?

Comment: No its not referenced in web.config